# Twitter bootstrap modal shows the same content each time I call it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a link to modal a lot of times. In this modal I can choose data from drop down list. But each time I call it, it shows the data of drop down list I chose the first time.

Here is how I call modal:

`<a data-toggle="modal" href="#example">...</a>`

This is my modal:

```
<div id="example" class="modal hide fade">  
    <div class="modal-header">  
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
        <h3>Choose subject and teacher</h3>  
    </div> 
    <div>
        <form class="contact" name = "form">
            <div class="modal-body">  
                <input type = "text" id = "secret" style = "display:none">  
                <select name="subjects" id="subjects" onchange="ch()">
                    <option selected disabled value="default">Subject</option>
                        <?php foreach($subjects as $subject): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"><?php echo $subject; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <div id = "filters"></div>  
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">  
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Save</button>  
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use events!

from doc: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

> Events Bootstrap's modal class exposes a few events for hooking into
>   modal functionality.

Example:

```
$('#example').on('show', function () {
  $('#subjects').val('default');
})
```